# How to figure out why cron is failing to run a script

Tags: cron

I need some troubleshooting help please.

I'm trying to run a script which copies the contents of one directory into another directory on a daily basis.  I can successfully run it manually with `./config-copy.sh` etc

```
SOURCE="/home/oxidized/.config/oxidized/logs/"
DESTINATION="/mnt/sync"
sudo cp -r "$SOURCE"* "$DESTINATION"
```

The script is in the home directory of the user oxidized. The oxidized user is a member of `sudo`.

I have this entry in crontab:

```
17 00 * * * /home/oxidized/config-copy.sh
```

This should run daily at 3pm but I can see the files in the destination directory are not being updated.

I have tried changing the copy command in the script with and without sudo but it did not make a difference.

There is nothing useful in `/var/log/syslog` or in `/var/log/cron.log`.

I have already tried restarting the cron process.

Comment: Hello. The mnt directory is usually only used as a mount point for external devices.  Such as if I had an external drive and I wanted to access it by SMB or NFS I would use a command to have it attached to a directory under mnt. You may want to start by using a different destination directory.

Comment: @David.  I am mounting a remote filesystem to sync with a local directory. /

Comment: @user68186.  I did use sudo crontab -e to create the job and I have tried running it with and without sudo.  I also tried running it with oxidized as the user but that didn't work either.

Comment: 1. Don't use `sudo` inside of `cron` it is already running with **sudo** privileges. 2. To find the error use `journalctl | grep` followed by the name of your cron script.

Comment: It would be a good idea to make that  clear in the question using edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `"$SOURCE"/*` is expanded by your current (non-`sudo`) shell, which, I assume, isn't accessible by `$USER`.

A better way is to have `root` expand the list of files and do the copy:

```
sudo find "$SOURCE" -type f -print0 | \
  xargs  -0 -r sudo cp -t "$DEST"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The command does exactly what one would expect but again it has not run with Cron.  

I get mail from Cron after it tries to run this job and it says "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper".  I don't know the root password so I can't login with it and create the job using that account.  I have to use sudo.